# Extracting HTML from url using Perl

Tags: html, perl, twiki

I want to extract the HTML code of a TWiki (who's URL i have). What is the best possible way of doing that?

Additionally, once i extract the HTML code i need to out it in a site hosted on Google Sites. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks. The LWP::Simple worked fine. But would anyone have any clue to the answer for my second question. I can't seem to access my site at all.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple way to get a HTML page is the [LWP::Simple](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aSimple) module. If you have to do a more complex navigation flow, then use [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize). Then, if you need to parse the HTML code, the @brian solution is good.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the CPAN [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm) module.

```
use HTML::Parser ();

 # Create parser object
 $p = HTML::Parser->new( api_version => 3,
                         start_h => [\&start, "tagname, attr"],
                         end_h   => [\&end,   "tagname"],
                         marked_sections => 1,
                       );
# Parse directly from file
 $p->parse_file("foo.html");
```

Comment: I don't recommend HTML::Parser, that module needs an annoying amount of code to achieve simple things. Better and declarative: [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web::Query) (CSS selectors), [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://p3rl.org/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath) (XPath)